# Multiple Domain Names - One WP Install (non-Multisite) - Default Each Domain name to Category Archive

Tags: categories, seo, domain-mapping, customization

Use case is somewhat simple  - here goes:

1. Five people share a single wordpress install - not multi-user
2. Each person blogs and puts their posts in a their own unique category
3. Each person has their own domain name
4. All domain names are pointed or parked to same WP install folder
5. Each person's domain name only shows the posts from their category, i.e.

   - http://blogger1.com would return category archive of Blogger1's posts,
   - http://blogger2.com would return category archive of Blogger2's posts,
   - etc.
6. Google friendly indexing for each domain name
7. Prefer rewrite solution rather than redirect but redirect is acceptable
8. A"master" account would be able to post or edit any of the bloggers posts via the "main" domain login.
9. Bonus  - if this could be extended to custom post types

Environment

1. One installation of latest version of WP (not multi-user)
2. Pretty Permalinks
3. Cpanel - to set up domain parking
4. No subdomains
5. Access to `.htaccess`
6. Access to `functions.php`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Multisite for this?

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to multisite, but more complicated, and the master account would just be a super admin user. As an aside, the domains here you'll want rewriting, but even then, permalink rewrite rules won't be able to handle this scenario, doing this will be fragile, take a lot of time to maintain, easily break, and be difficult to implement. Multisite on the other hand does all of this by design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's two different solutions *(editing the specifics for your use case)*:

### Doing a Redirect:

1.) At the top of your `/wp-config.php` file add the following:

```
if ( is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ) {
  $domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $domain );
  define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $domain );
} else if ( ! is_main_domain( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ) {
  header( "Location:http://{$yoursite_main_domain}", true, 301 );
  exit;
}
function is_main_domain( $domain ) {
  $domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
  return strpos( $domain, 'maindomain.com' ) !== false;
}
function is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $domain ) {
  $domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
  return in_array( $domain, array(
    'blogger1.com',
    'blogger2.com',
    'blogger3.com',
    'blogger4.com',
    'blogger5.com',
    'uncategorized.dev', // Only here for use on my own test site
   ) );
}
```

2.) Then add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yoursite_template_redirect' );
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
  $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($path,"/category/") === false) {
    $domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ;
    $category = str_replace( '.com', '', $domain );
    $category = str_replace( '.dev', '', $domain );  // Only for my own test site
    $location = "http://{$domain}/category/{$category}/" ;
      wp_safe_redirect( $location );
      exit;
    }
  }
}
```

The above will do a 302 redirect to `http://blogger1.com/category/blogger1/` when a request is made of any URL `http://blogger1.com` other than one that starts with `http://blogger1.com/category/` *(you made need to make some changes to support other URLs.)*

### Doing a *"Rewrite":*

What the above does not support is *"rewrite"* vs. a *"redirect"* solution. If you want to that it is a little more complicated. The following code will result in the category page being loaded in the root path for any domain that is mapped in your `is_yoursite_blogger_domain()` function. Of course your `is_yoursite_blogger_domain()` function could be validating against existing categories but I don't know the full criteria so I just hard coded it. You can copy this code into your function's `theme.php` file or put into a `.php` file of a plugin you might be writing. Note that this code also requires the code in the `/wp-config.php` file above:

```
add_action( 'category_link', 'yoursite_category_link', 11, 2 );
function yoursite_category_link( $category_link, $category_id ) {
  // Make sure any blogger category links are truncated to the root
  $parts = explode( '/', $category_link );
  if ( is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $parts[2] ) ) {
    // if %category% in http://%domain%/category/%category%/ 
    // equals %domain% minus the 'com' extension
    if ( "{$parts[4]}." == substr( $parts[2], 0, strlen( $parts[4] ) + 1 ) ) {
     $category_link = "http://{$parts[2]}/"; // Strip 'category/%category%/'
    }
  }
  return $category_link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'yoursite_init' );
function yoursite_init() {
  // Remove the canonical redirect to the category page
  // if %category% in http://%category%.%ext%/ is a blogger category.
  if ( is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ) {
    $parts = explode( '/', strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
    if (count($parts) > 1) {
      $category_base = get_option( 'category_base' );
      if ( empty( $category_base ) )
        $category_base = 'category';
      if ( $category_base == $parts[1] ) {
        remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
      }
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yoursite_template_redirect' );
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
  // Redirect any http://%category%.%ext%/category/%category%/ to http://%category%.%ext%/
  if ( is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) ) {
    $category_base = get_option('category_base');
    if (empty($category_base))
      $category_base = 'category';
    $parts = explode( '/', strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
    if ( $category_base == $parts[1] &&
       "{$parts[2]}." == substr( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, strlen( $parts[2] ) + 1 ) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( "http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/", 301 );
      exit;
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'request', 'yoursite_request' );
function yoursite_request($query_vars) {
  // If %category% in http://%category%.%ext%/ is a blogger category set the
  // 'category_name' query var to tell WordPress to display the category page.
  $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  if ( is_yoursite_blogger_domain( $domain ) ) {
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( strpos( $path, "/category/" ) === false ) {
      $domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $domain ) ;
      $category_name = substr( $domain, 0, strrpos( $domain, '.' ) );
      $query_vars = array( 'category_name' => $category_name );
    }
  }
  return $query_vars;
}
```

And here's a screen shot to show the second example in action:

[image: Screenshot of a WordPress site using hooks to enable a category page to be displayed in the URL root for selected categories]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110416-182443.png))</sub>

Another probably better way to approach this would be with a custom taxonomy instead of categories, or even better yet, map the domain to a user name instead. That way it's less work on the authors and you don't have to worry about maintaining the blogger list in code or in a separate taxonomy list.

As for you *"bonus"*, sorry but I don't follow what you want there.

Comment: custom taxonomy instead of categories - this was the bonus

Comment: this is an awesome solution. I left out a use case. The "master" account would be able to post or edit any of the bloggers posts via the "main" domain login. It seems here that you must be logged in on the domain name to see any of the posts. What would be great is to be able to exclude the main domain name from the rewrite so it can edit any post.

Comment: Call to undefined function wp_safe_redirect() in /home/targeted/public_html/wp-config.php on line 3 I get this error if I use non-listed domain - I assume the function isnt loaded at this point

Comment: @aj martin - I've updated the code to address your "main domain requirement and fixed the bug you found.  As for a custom taxonomy, maybe another day. :)

Comment: @aj martin - Also please update your question with your new requirement so that someone who finds this question via SEO won't be confused if they only read your question and not the comments.

Comment: mike - thanks so much - you are the wordpress wizard !!

Comment: @aj martin - Glad I could help.

Comment: one more thing I noticed  -  how does it handle www.blogger1.com etc.   when I add the www subdomain I get blank page

Comment: @aj martin - I updated the code for `is_main_domain()` and for  `is_yoursite_blogger_domain()` to enable a `'www.'` to slip through.

Comment: @aj martin - You are welcome.

Comment: Mike  - use case has changed slightly on this one  - should i post here or create a new question?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but with pages instead of posts. I've posted a comment on StackOverflow [Multiple simple wordpress sites (different domains) on a single installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107838/multiple-simple-wordpress-sites-different-domains-on-a-single-installation)... is your answer easily adaptable to this case?

Comment: downvoted as the right answer is to use a multisite. in 4.7 this kind of setup will probably break the rest API in addition to other thing it would break in any case like search

Comment: Thank you for the awesome solution. I was wondering, how can I assign different themes for each of the websites? (I guess using https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/ would be a solution, yet there should be better solutions)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the domain alias(es)
2. Add this to your wp-config file:

   ```
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
   define('WP_HOME','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
   ```
3. Go to your theme and add something like this to load the main content (used this for a one pager):

   ```
   $home=get_page_by_path(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, strlen($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])-4));
   echo do_shortcode($home->post_content);
   ```
4. change the categorie, page or post slug to the domain name min the toplevel domain, in this case a toplevel domain only with 4 characters. For example: .com .net .org if you want to use something like .nl .be or .de than you should change the 4 into a 3. If you wanna use both than you've to add conditions.

**Note:** This may only work for one page, but I'm only giving you the idea. You can expand the functionality of the code yourself if it's necessary