# Have different site location for wp-admin in IIS

Tags: wp-admin, iis, ssl

I'm attempting to put a WordPress blog on a Windows server. PHP and WordPress installed just fine, and I have a working website, and admin site. However, I want to access the wp-admin directory using SSL (with a self-signed cert that I installed).

I'm also looking to have the SSL cert only be used for admin, by me - I understand the browser warnings, and it will be on a funky port, but obviously I don't want regular users to have to deal with this.

Everything works fine if I tell the WordPress settings that my site lives on https://example.com:4443/ - I can get to the entire site, including admin, using that URL. However, http://example.com/ does not work when I do this.

I'm looking for a way to have the best of both worlds - SSL on a funky port for admin, and regular HTTP on port 80 for the rest of the site, but I can't seem to figure out how to have two different URLs. Is this possible?

The issue is definitely with WordPress - IIS and PHP are perfectly fine running in both worlds simultaneously, but the app itself doesn't work.

I've got full server rights, so I can do whatever crazy IIS settings or php.ini settings are needed.

Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: This may help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/multiple-domain-names-one-wp-install-non-multisite-default-each-domain-nam

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm skeptical. Redirect definitely won't help since it's just going to send me to the other location which I know doesn't work. I don't know about rewrite - since I'm dealing with HTTP and HTTPS, I don't know if URL rewriting will allow you to change ports - every example I've ever seen for HTTP->HTTPS always does a redirect, not a rewrite. But I'll give it a shot tonight, thanks.