# Wordpress author url to alias domain url? domain.com/author/{username}/

Tags: url-rewriting

It's possible to create alias domain automatically for new authors? Currently, the author profile URL is -> example.com/author/username I'm using ISPCONFIG 3 as control panel

What do I have to do to achieve it?

1. example.com/author/username  -> username.example.com
2. example.com/author/username1 -> username1.example.com
3. example.com/author/username2 -> username2.example.com

etc...

Comment: Maybe this answer should help you? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174074/136456