# Multiple Domain Names - One WP Install (non-Multisite) - Default Each Domain name to Product Category WooCommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Based on this answer, we can map multiple domain with multiple post categories, [Multiple Domain Names - One WP Install (non-Multisite) - Default Each Domain name to Category Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/multiple-domain-names-one-wp-install-non-multisite-default-each-domain-nam?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now i am trying to achieve the same with Woocommerce product categories.
Basically i am trying to build a multi store using the woocomerce product categories.
http://baby.mydomain.com => will serve the existing product  belonging to the root category "baby"
http://adult.mydomain.com => will serve the existing product  belonging to the root category "adult"

Actually I need a single cart trough out the multi-stores, that is why i am having this approach. Currently Wocommerce can not handle a global cart inside a multi site network

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: gut feeling is that the amount of things that might get wrong with that answer is huge. Use multisite if you need different domains (one of the things that obviously will go wrong is search results, tags etc which are quite important to shops).

Comment: thanks. Actually I need a single cart trough out the multi-stores, that is why i am having this approach. Currently Wocommerce can not handle a global cart inside a multi site network

Comment: I guess the more important question is why to have the separation at all?

Comment: the client need a multistore with a different branding, but a single global cart.

Comment: not sure how multisite conflict with having one cart, there migh not be any plugin that supports it, but it should be possible. Your proposed solution will actually not work for the reasons I specified.

Comment: WooCommerce is not compatible with WPMultisite to handle one single cart. Meaning if you have 3 sub sites, you will have 3 shops with 3 different carts, this is not what the client is requiring unfrotunately

Comment: well, there is no technical reason for that, while there are technical reason no to do it your way. You should tak it with their support

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can fix that for you: https://wooglobalcart.com/